# Non-dimensionalise this ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, transformation, dimensional-analysis

I have the ODE:

\begin{equation}
    \frac{dx}{dt} = ax - \frac{b}{b + x} x
\end{equation}

where $a$ has units $[1/t]$ and $b$ has units $[x/t]$. $x$, in this example, is a resource, and the last term describes consumption rate, which cannot go above $x$.

I would like to non-dimensionalize the equation, but I'm running into problems with the consumption term. Here's my working:

Define the dimensionless variables:

\begin{equation}
    \hat{t} = \frac{t}{t^{*}}, \quad
    \hat{x} = \frac{x}{x^{*}}
\end{equation}

Rewrite the ODE:

\begin{equation}
    \frac{d\hat{x}x^{*}}{d\hat{t}{t^{*}}} = a \hat{x}x^{*} - \frac{b}{b + \hat{x}x^{*}}\hat{x}x^{*}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
    \frac{d\hat{x}}{d\hat{t}} = a t^{*} \hat{x} - t^{*} \frac{b}{b + \hat{x}x^{*}}\hat{x}
\end{equation}

Define $t^{*} = a$ and $x^{*} = b/a$, then:

\begin{equation}
     \frac{d\hat{x}}{d\hat{t}} = a \hat{x} - \frac{1}{a} \frac{b}{b + \hat{x} \frac{b}{a}}\hat{x}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
     \frac{d\hat{x}}{d\hat{t}} = a \hat{x} - \frac{1}{a} \frac{1}{1 + \hat{x} \frac{1}{a}}\hat{x}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
     \frac{d\hat{x}}{d\hat{t}} = a \hat{x} - \frac{1}{a} \frac{1}{ \frac{a + \hat{x}}{a}}\hat{x}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
     \frac{d\hat{x}}{d\hat{t}} = a \hat{x} - \frac{1}{a} \frac{a}{a + \hat{x}}\hat{x}
\end{equation}

which gives us

\begin{equation}
     \frac{d\hat{x}}{d\hat{t}} = a \hat{x} - \frac{1}{a + \hat{x}}\hat{x}
\end{equation}

However, the consumption term is not non-dimensionalized as it still has units of time.

I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: There's something wrong in your original equation if the dimension of $x$ and $t$ are different. How can you sum $x$ and $b$ in the denominator if they have different dimensions?

Comment: Hmm, I didn't think this was an issue actually (sorry, I'm still learning!). Do you mean the dimensions of $x$ and $b$ (not $x$ and $t$)? $b$ is meant to be a fixed demand, and the last term is meant to stop consumption being greater than the amount of $x$.

Comment: Yea, you added two things of different dimensions (x and b). Unless your definitions/ assumptions are wrong.

Comment: @BenjaminWang Thanks. I was trying to find a function for consumption that did not exceed the quantity of resource $x$, even if $b$ was set to be $>> x$. The function $b/(K + b)$, where $K$ has dimensions of $[x/t]$ as well is possible, but doesn't really work as well. Essentially, I want consumption to equal $b$ as long as $b < x$, but equal $x$ when $x < b$.

Comment: softmax or sigmoid function might help